# $routerCanActivate not working (Angular 1.5 component router aka ngComponentRouter)

Tags: angularjs, ngcomponentrouter

First of all, yes, I know ngComponentRouter module is depracated but my app is already working quite well using it other than this one issue.

The issue is that $routerCanActivate function is not firing (search for "$routerCanActivate" in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component-router to see how it should work).

Can anyone provide example of it working ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$canActivate` for static property.